# the codenameon demos under netbean 3.2 do not work

Tags: codenameone

IDE: NetBeans 8.2
Windows 7

I installed codenameone under NB 8.2 and can't get a demo to load. They all say 'The project source/binary format is older than minimal supported one (1.6).'

Also can't get the codenameone plugin to update.

any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with older plugins which should work for `3.5.6` or newer.

As a workaround make sure the project is set to use Java 8 and open the build.xml file. Replace all references to `1.5` to `1.8`.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my "Resolve Project Problems", but I still get this error when running the ToDoApp (and others) :

/Users/nnnnn/netbeans-tutorial/All-codenameone-demos/ToDoApp/build.xml:51: taskdef class com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

- none of these hints helped me: https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_fix_the_libs
- MacOs 10.14.6, Netbeans 12.2,

Now I came a little longer as I in preferences, Java added, Add JAR/ZIP:
.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar